# Servlet springapp is not available

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple spring app that I'm trying to run on Tomcat 7.

My web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>
     index.jsp
   </welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Then I have a springapp-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

 <bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/>

</beans>
```

My actual controller is:

```
package springapp.web;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException{

    System.out.println("Returning hello view");
    return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
  }
}
```

I have two jsp's that I can browse straight to, index.jsp and hello.jsp, but when I try to browse to localhost:8080/springapp/hello.htm, I get an error that says that Servlet springapp is not available. I tried several things including different versions of Spring Framework, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is the exact URL that works to browse `home.jsp` ? IMHO the correct URL to reach your controller is same URL changing `jsp` with `htm`

Answer (score 0):

Might have error in xml parsing because you forgot to close the string

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
```

change it to

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
```

same with

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
```

change it to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Comment: I can try that. I would expect to get an error in my IDE if I had some syntax issues like that. Maybe not, though.

Comment: you need to update you preferences in you IDE and install web related plugins. im using eclipse (please hit good stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had some errors on startup referring to not being able to load certain 64-bit .dll's on a 32-bit platform. Realized I was trying to run this on a 64-bit version of tomcat. Downloaded new version and everything worked properly.